# Windows Keyboard Shortcut for switching multiple Screens

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, external-display

I have three monitors and due to the video card restrictions, I can only view two monitors at a time. Everytime I want to switch between the monitors, I would have to open the "Display settings", click on the third screen, and then on the "Multiple Displays" dropdown, and select "Extend desktop to this display" as shown in the screenshot below. Is there any Keyboard shortcut I can set so that it could automatically do this?

Comment: Get better GPU ^^ :p

Comment: lol its an almost 7yrs old computer, so didn't feel like upgrading anything on it :P

Comment: I wasn't entirely serious :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Ultramon software](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). Then I created two Display Profiles, with the sets up monitors I want to use. Each profiles create a desktop shortcuts. Then I went to the properties of each of those shortcuts and I was able to set the keyboard shortcut.